# SED: Use sed command to replace text with raw value of a variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to use `sed` to replace a text with a variable value.

The variable `regex` holds a regular expression as a value:

```
regex=^/v(\d+)/stats.(xml|json)(.*)$
```

The `sed` command I'm trying looks like this:

```
sed 's/?PATH_REGEX/'"$regex"'/g' <<<"$templateEscapedForSed"
```

The `$templateEscapedForSed` variable holds a simple template shown below. In this case I'm trying to replace '?PATH_REGEX' with a value of the `$regex` variable.

```
$templateEscapedForSed holds the following:

location ~* ?PATH_REGEX {
            rewrite ?PATH_REGEX ?URL break;
    }
```

When the value of the `$regex` is a simple text without any special characters (e.g. "test") this sed command works ok:

```
location ~* test {\
        rewrite test ?URL break;\
}
```

However when the `regex` variable holds the regular expression mentioned above I'm getting an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'
```

I suspect the value of the `regex` variable is being interpreted and thus causing an error.

What I want to get in the result is:

```
location ~* ^/v(\d+)/stats.(xml|json)(.*)$ {
            rewrite ^/v(\d+)/stats.(xml|json)(.*)$ ?URL break;
    }
```

Is there a way to just insert the value of the `regex` variable 'as is'?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern answer your uestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's conflict due to slashes being present in the value of the `regex` variable. However, `sed` allows its `s` command to use a different separator. The first character after the `s` command becomes the separator. For example, all these are equivalent:

```
s/.../.../g
s|...|...|g
s;...;...;g
```

So, use a delimiter that's not part of the string used as a replacement:

```
sed "s;?PATH_REGEX;$regex;g" <<<"$templateEscapedForSed"
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this sed behavior. This solves my problem. Thank you very much!